# Bar construction for spectra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces

Suppose we have a group $G$ then one can construct $BG$ and one of the essential part of the construction is the co-unit map. Now suppose we have a ring spectrum $R$, then having a co-unit splits the ring spectrum as $R = S \vee R'$, which is never an interesting case.

So my question is what is the best one can do? I know its a vague question. But is there an alternative thing that one can do, which closely resembles bar construction that one does for a group?

Comment: I don't see an analogy in your proposal since you don't take any bar construction on $R$. The 'bar construction' on $R$ would be the topological Hochschild homology spectrum $THH(R)$, which has a 'counit' $TTH(R)\rightarrow R$.

Comment: Prasit: Such a thing does work in a good category of spectra, and in fact it is the case that you can split of the unit in a similar way to get a reduced bar construction. I will look around for the right diagram, I can't recall it off the top of my head.

Comment: To add to Sean's comments, the two-sided bar construction B(M,A,N) can be formed in myriads of contexts in which one has a monoid A in a monoidal category with right action on M and left action on N. Topological groups G and ring spectra R are just two examples.  The fact that you can't generally take M=S in general in the ring spectra example is not so important.  The precise relationship with THH is on pp 173-174 of EKMM. 

Comment: These are all really helpful comments! I will look into the references. 

Comment: Edit: Fernando: There is a bar construction for spectra and it does not necessarily give you $THH$. The naive two sided bar construction $B(M,A,N)$ frequently models $M \wedge_A N$, there are some cellularity (is that a word) hypotheses. The cyclic bar construction is an example of the two sided bar construction. This can all be found in EKMM.

Comment: I took $THH(R)$ to be the 'right' notion of $BG$ for ring spectra because, as the later, computes the 'right' homology theory of the kind of object under consideration, but of course Prasit may have in mind something closed to what you and Peter May suggest.

Comment: Why is it uninteresting for $S$ to split off of $R$?  Doesn't this happen in the case that $R = \Sigma^\infty G_+$ for a group $G$?  The associated Tor spectrum $Tor^R(S, S)$ (or derived smash product of $S$ with itself over $R$) will then compute the suspension spectrum of $BG$, certainly an interesting object.

Comment: I did not know this, and certainly this is very interesting. It seems slightly out of context of what I am interested( which right now is hard to describe). But thanks for pointing this out. I will keep in mind.

Comment: @SeanTilson: what is understood as the cyclic bar construction, really?

Comment: The cyclic bar construction is like the two sided bar construction $B(M,A,N)$ except that instead of $M$ and $N$ being different they are replaced by a single $A$ bimodule. The Hochschild complex is the classic example.